# Weird behaviour of Plot

Tags: plotting

I tried to execute this simple command

```
Plot[Cosh[t] - Sinh[t] + Sin[t], {t, 0, 40}]
```

and this is the result I got

[image]

As you can see, there is an unexpected visual between $t=30$ and $t=40$. But when I used the identity $e^{-t}=\cosh{t}-\sinh{t}$, everything went fine. This command

```
Plot[Exp[-t] + Sin[t], {t, 0, 40}]
```

gives

[image]

What's going on here? Can anyone reproduce this result? Is this a bug? I'm using MMA 12 64bit on Windows 10.

Comment: Try the MaxRecursion option for Plot. It is generally used to control adaptive sampling.

Comment: Both $\cosh x$ and $\sinh x$ functions are diverging at large positive $x$ as $e^x$. For these values are hard to achieve perfect cancellation between the two functions. $e^{-x}$ does not have this problem. Use `WorkingPrecision -> 30` option of `Plot` to get the same result.

Comment: `Plot[Cosh[t] - Sinh[t] + Sin[t], {t, 0, 40}, PlotPoints -> 4]` this can partly solve it.

Comment: The same happens for me (v11 on Windows 10), `WorkingPrecision -> 20` corrects it.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a problem with your main file. I tried your command and the result is ok. My `Mma` version is `12`.